# Webclient returning Optional.empty() on not found response

Tags: java, spring-webclient

I'm trying to make `WebClient` return an `Optional.empty()` when I get a 404, not found, from the server. But instead I get a Optional with a `User` object with all properties set to null.

What am I missing?

```
@Override
public Optional<User> getUser(Username username) {
    return webClient
            .get()
            .uri(buildUrl(username))
            .retrieve()
            .onStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND::equals, response -> Mono.empty())
            .onStatus(HttpStatus::is4xxClientError, response -> createError(response, CLIENTERROR))
            .onStatus(HttpStatus::is5xxServerError, response -> createError(response, SERVRERROR))
            .bodyToMono(User.class)
            .blockOptional();
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can make use of onError* functions from Mono to handle these cases.

`onErrorResume` to create a empty/error Mono on exception and `onErrorMap` to transform exception to a different exception type.

For example:

```
@Override
public Optional<User> getUser(Username username) {
    return webClient
            .get()
            .uri(buildUrl(username))
            .retrieve()
            .onStatus(httpStatus -> httpStatus.is4xxClientError() && httpStatus != HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, response -> createError(response, CLIENTERROR))
            .onStatus(HttpStatus::is5xxServerError, response -> createError(response, SERVRERROR))
            .bodyToMono(User.class)
            .onErrorResume(WebClientResponseException.NotFound.class, notFound -> Mono.empty())
            .blockOptional();
}
```

Comment: Note that the "onStatus" calls are not necessary to solve the original problem. 
The "onErrorResume" call does the requested job.

Comment: Shame there isnt a built in feature in the Spring WebClient to allow this to work

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the sample code from WebClient Javadoc ([javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/WebClient.ResponseSpec.html#onStatus-java.util.function.Predicate-java.util.function.Function-)). It does exactly that using Mono's onErrorResume Method:

```
 webClient.get()
   .uri("https://example.com/account/123")
   .retrieve()
   .bodyToMono(Account.class)
   .onErrorResume(WebClientResponseException.class,
        ex -> ex.getRawStatusCode() == 404 ? Mono.empty() : Mono.error(ex));
```